# Trouble with JSON.Parse - console shows error in DOCTYPE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to write some JSON data to a div with JQuery:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$('#container').html(obj.services.service[0].code);
```

But I get an error saying there is a Syntax error in my DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I read in other posts that this could be because of quotation marks around the JSON object. I have tried to add different quotes around the JSON object but with no luck, eg: `var obj = JSON.parse("'" + data + "'");`

I am not sure how to tackle this one. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

The JSON data looks like:

```
{
  "services": {
    "service" : [
      {
        "code": "AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR",
        "name": "Parcel Post (your own packaging)",
        "speed": 2,
        "price": 6.95,
        "max_extra_cover": 5000,
        "extra_cover_rule": "100,1.5,1.5",
        "icon_url": "http://test-static.npe.auspost.com.au/api/images/pac/regular_post_box.png",
        "description": "Based on the size and weight you've entered",
        "details": "Check our ",
        "delivery_time": "Delivered in up to 3 business days",
        "ui_display_order": 1,
        "options": {
          "option": [
            {
```

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'AusPostDomestic.php',
            data: {toPostcode: toPostcodeValue, parcelLengthInCMs: parcelLengthInCMsValue, parcelHeighthInCMs: parcelHeighthInCMsValue, parcelWidthInCMs: parcelWidthInCMsValue, parcelWeightInKGs: parcelWeightInKGsValue},
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#auspostresult').html(obj.services.service[0].code);
            }
```

Comment: Where does `data` come from?

Comment: is JSON.parse a problem or writing to element using .html() ?

Comment: @dfsq added my AJAX that creates data above

Comment: You have alreadyb added datatype as json , no need to parse it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have alreadyb added datatype as json , no need to parse it again. So remove line `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` from your success callback function.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  url: 'AusPostDomestic.php',
  data: {
    toPostcode: toPostcodeValue,
    parcelLengthInCMs: parcelLengthInCMsValue,
    parcelHeighthInCMs: parcelHeighthInCMsValue,
    parcelWidthInCMs: parcelWidthInCMsValue,
    parcelWeightInKGs: parcelWeightInKGsValue
  },
  success: function(obj) {
    //console.log(data);
    $('#auspostresult').html(obj.services.service[0].code);
  }
});
```

Api Doc : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/